# Отслеживание изменения и валидация параметров ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Используя свойства, мы можем отследить их изменения в методе set. Если встает вопрос о валидации, нужно просто реализовать интерфейс IDataErrorInfo и прописать нужную логику вывода ошибок в индексаторе. Собственно, так я и делаю:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowVM/>
</Window.Datacontext>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Value = "/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SingleParameter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="30" Height="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error => null;

    public double SingleParameter { get; set; }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = null;

            try
            {
                var parameter = new Parameter("Item", SingleParameter);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error = e.Message;
            }

            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

**Parameter.cs:**

```
public class Parameter
{
    private double _value;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Значение не может быть отрицательным");
            }

            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public Parameter(string name, double value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

И это работает:

[image: Корректный ввод] [image: Некорректный ввод]

Но как сделать то же самое с параметрами, выводимыми списком ItemTemplate? Я пытаюсь так:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="30" Height="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error => null;

    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Params { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Params = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>
        {
            new Parameter("Param1 = ", 10),
            new Parameter("Param2 = ", 20),
            new Parameter("Param3 = ", 30),
            new Parameter("Param4 = ", 40),
            new Parameter("Param5 = ", 50)
        };
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = null;

            foreach(var param in Params)
            {
                try
                {
                    var parameter = new Parameter("Item", param.Value);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    error = e.Message;
                }
            }

            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

Но это не работает:

[image: Корректный ввод] [image: Некорректный ввод]

Как обеспечивается валидация параметров, выведенных с помощью ItemTemplate? Если это делается как-то по-другому, я буду рад любой информации, но так же мне интересно, как правильно непосредственно отследить изменение параметра, если это понадобится, к примеру, для изменения каких-либо свойств, лежащих во вью-модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не работал с `IDataErrorInfo`, но опыт интересный.

Не знаю, насколько это правильно или нет, но у меня получилось вот так. Дополнительно прикрутил тултип, показывающий, что за ошибка возникла.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                                        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" 
                                        Width="30" Height="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class Parameter : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private double _value;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _validationErrors;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                SetValidationError("Значение не может быть отрицательным");
            else
                ClearValidationError();
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public string Error => null;

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            _validationErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out string message);
            return message;
        }
    }

    private void ClearValidationError([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
        => _validationErrors.Remove(propertyName);

    private void SetValidationError(string message, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
        => _validationErrors[propertyName] = message;

    public Parameter(string name, double value)
    {
        _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А как с помощью этого способа можно оповестить вью-модель окна об изменении параметра? К примеру, если при изменении какого-либо параметра, нужно вызывать определенный метод вью-модели окна, передавая в него новое значение параметра.

Comment: @Vladislav передавайте в конструктор `Parameter` ссылку на экземпляр вьюмодели. Только не совсем понятно, зачем такое делать. Если вам нужно из вьюмодели провалидировать всю коллекцию с `Parameter`, вы можете воспользоваться тем же интерфейсом `IDataErrorInfo` и пробежаться по индексаторам в цикле для каждого `Parameter`. Точно так же как это делает WPF для отображения ошибки валидации. Если ответ был полезен, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым. Галочка слева от ответа. Если у вас есть другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @Vladislav если вам просто нужно посчитать количество ошибок валидации, можете в `Parameter` завести публичное свойство например `public int ErrorsCount => _validationErrors.Count;` посчитать количество ошибок суммарно для всей коллекции можно будет даже с помощью простого Linq запроса `int errorsCount = Params.Sum(p => p.ErrorsCount);`.

Comment: @Vladislav кстати, своим новым вопросам с кодом C# добавляйте тег `c#`, тогда их увидит больше участников.

Comment: помимо валидации нужно при изменении каждого параметра коллекции, лежащей во вью-модели вызывать метод, который будет проводить нужные дальнейшие манипуляции. Т.е. изменился первый параметр коллекции -> во вью-модели вызвался метод CollectionItemChanged(), то же самое - со вторым параметром коллекции, с третьим и т.д. Передача в конструктор параметра ссылки на вью-модель звучит, как рабочий вариант, но насколько это правильно? При попытке сделать то же самое с IDataErrorInfo (что и описано в вопросе), при изменении параметра коллекции, компилятор даже не заходит в get() индексатора.

Comment: Ваш ответ оказался полезным и я его приму, просто хотелось бы кое-каких уточнений

Comment: @Vladislav я не понимаю, зачем вам вызывать какой-то метод в главной вьюмодели? Неизвестно какую задачу вы решаете, а звучит она странно. Единственное очевидное решение, если вы не расскажете в деталях, зачем это вам - передача в конструктор. Это как бы единственный путь, если вы хотите получить циклическую зависимость (зависимость от старшего класса - циклическая), которых в принципе следует избегать. А как избежать - непонятно, потому что непонятно, зачем это всё надо.

Comment: Хорошо. Задача такая: есть список параметров, как в нашем случае. Есть некий графический компонент, который напрямую зависит от этих самых параметров. При изменении каждого из этих параметров, графический компонент должен перерисовываться, принимая на вход, соответственно, обновленные параметры. Параметры должны быть корректными, отсюда вопрос валидации, также нужно как-то понять, что коллекция претерпела изменения, чтобы вызвать метод отрисовки, отсюда и необходимость соответствующего метода во вью-модели

Comment: @Vladislav так это просто, чтобы узнать, что свойство поменялось, надо подписаться на событие `Parameter.PropertyChanged`, плюс проверить, провалидирован ли он запросив ошибку из индексатора. Решение очень простое и не требует циклической зависимости. `param.PropertyChaned += (s, e) => { if (s is Parameter p && e.PropertyName == nameof(p.Value) && p[e.PropertyName] is null) { параметр изменился и провалидирован без ошибки } };` при добавлении нового параметра в коллекцию `Params` нужно подписаться на событие, при удалении - отписаться.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это как раз то, что мне было нужно!