Как правильно делать валидацию, чтобы не делать проверку на тип
Есть метод, который добавляет документ и закрывает окно. Нужно до добавления документа провести валидацию, но документ может иметь разный тип, то есть количество и название разных свойств. Как я понимаю делать проверку на тип не правильно, чтобы сделать валидацию (На пустые свойства, правильный набор и т.д.).
Как правильно (без проверки на тип) сделать универсальную валидацию для всех типов документов.
void AddDocument(DocumentBaseViewModel document)
{
    _repository.AddDocument(document);
    _serviceView.Close<DocumentViewModel>();
}


Что такое "документ" и о каких "типах" идет речь?

Собственные классы представляющие собой паспорт, СНИЛС и так далее, каждый из этих классов содержит разное количество свойств и названий, наследуются от базового класса documentbaseviewmodel там одинаковые свойства для других документов.

Так... И почему вы должны их валидировать? По каким вообще параметрам?

Когда отправляю в репощиторий, хотелось бы проверять каждое свойство на пустоту, или на набор определенных значений, где то цифры, где то буквы, где то определенное из кол-во и так далее)

Сделайте отдельный метод для валидации каждого типа документа и вызывайте нужный метод когда валидируете.

Я хотел сделать отдельный метод но там нужно сделать проверку на тип документа чтобы определить какую валидацию применять, а это по идее не правильно делать проверку на тип(но это самый простой и легкий вариант), может быть есть какой-то правильный вариант или же лучше проверить по типу?

можете и по типу проверить или словарик сделать с проверяющими, или через dynamic - как вам удобней, главное, чтобы процесс этого выбора в один метод уложился. Потом придет новая идея - метод перепишите и всё

Понял, можно по простому без велосипедов, спасибо)

@tym32167 dynamic рудимент языка.

У WPF есть инструменты валидации https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280069/373567, https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php Другими словами, сама валидация должна быть реализована внутри документа. Затем можно вызвать bool isValidated = document.Error is null; А вообще к такой системе легко подключить валидацию на уровне интерфейса. Тогда при сохранении класс будет точно валидным и дополнительные проверки не потребуются.

@aepot точно можно же на уровне Vm документа делать проверку, а не в главной VM, замылились мысли), спасибо
